# ServiceStack - Request Binding JSON encoded parameter

Tags: servicestack

I have an existing application that sends a Request with a parameter named 'filters'. The 'filters' parameter contains a string that is JSON encoded. Example:

```
[{"dataIndex":"fieldName", "value":"fieldValue"}, {"dataIndex":"field2", "value":"value2"}].
```

Using ServiceStack, I would like to bind this as a property on a C# object (class Grid). **Is there a preferred method to handle this?** Here are the options I can think of. I don't think either 'feel' correct.

**Option 1:**
I do have a 'ServiceModel' project and this would create a dependency on it which I don't really like.
In AppHost.Configure() method add

```
RequestBinders[typeof(Grid)] => httpReq => { 
  return new Grid() { 
    Filters = new ServiceStack.Text.JsonSerializer<IList<Filter>>().DeserializeFromString(httpReq.QueryString["filters"])
  }
}
```

**Option 2:**
Seems kind of 'hacky'

```
public class Grid
{
  private string _filters;
  public dynamic Filters { 
    get 
    {
      ServiceStack.Text.JsonSerializer<IList<Filter().DeserializeFromString(_filters);
    }
    set
    {
      _filters = value;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can [send Complex objects in ServiceStack](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Serialization-deserialization) using the [JSV Format](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Text/wiki/JSV-Format).

If you want to send JSON via the QueryString you can access it from inside your Service of Request filters with something like:

```
public object Any(Request req) {
    var filters = base.Request.QueryString["Filters"].FromJson<List<Filter>>();
}
```

Note: [Interfaces on DTOs are bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10759250/85785).

Comment: Eliminated the double quotes and whitespace to comply with the JSV format and the default binding 'just works'. One pitfall is that I am using the ExtJS library which seems to escape all the characters in the url so I do need to get around that. Thanks!