# reconstituting property of type object with Servicestack.Text

Tags: c#, json, servicestack

I'm using the Servicestack.Text package to serialize and deserialize objects to and from JSON. One of my objects has a property of type object (System.Object). It is one of three things: a long, a double, a string. However, when I use JsonSerializer.DeserializeFromString it is always deserialized as a string. I need it deserialized as the type it was when it was serialized. I tried including the type information with JsConfig.IncludeTypeInfo = true; however, that only appears to apply to the class level, not the property level. How do I make this work?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is not supported in [ServiceStack JSON Serializer](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Text) which looks at the target type that it's deserializing into for info on how to coerce the JSON value.

Because you're using an `object` property there is no type info so it then fallsback and looks for existence of a **__type** property for this info, but ServiceStack never emits __type information for ValueTypes as it considerably bloats the payload.

With no type info to go on, the serializer just leaves the value as a string which is an object.

I recommend avoiding the use of interfaces, late-bound object types, etc which are a [bad idea to have on DTOs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10759250/85785), but for this you could create an extension method that inspects the string value and returns an instance of the correct type based on the contents, e.g:

```
var dto = new WildCard { AnyObject = 1 };

dto.AnyObject.AsJsonValue(); //Extension method that

"1" -> int 1
"true" -> bool true
"anything else" -> string "anything else"
```

The only issue with this is not being able to send a string literal containing a number or boolean value as it always gets coerced into their respective types.

Comment: What do you mean by "extension method" in this context? Is there some way to customize serialization on a per-property basis? And what would you think of an property attribute to force __type data to be written regardless of datatype and global settings?

Comment: In fact, it seems to me that we should always write __type data when serializing something of type object. How will we get it back otherwise?

Comment: Updated to show extension method. It only emits __type info when the object property is a reference type.

Comment: I ended up adding a second property that got the DataMember attribute and formatted/parsed the data going/coming.