# RouteAttribute, AttributeUsage, Inherited = true

Tags: servicestack

I currently have inheritance between DTO's which works well as long as I have for each concrete (leaf-node) DTO a [Route] defined, and not on one of the superclasses. Up until now the superclasses were all abstract. Now I'm in the situation where I have a DTO which is concrete and has a [Route] attribute defined is also a superclass of another DTO with it's own route.

Both DTO's have their own services, but it does not work as expected. Both DTO's are  "routed"  to the leaf-node.

```
superclass DTOA
subclass DTOB where DTOB : DTOA
```

when I do a GET on DTOA it is the service for DTOB that responds. Apart from modeling my inheritance different, how can I fix that the routes work as I had hoped they would?

therefore:

```
DTOA routed to serviceA
DTOB routed to serviceB
```

Is this happening because of the fact that RouteAttributes are inherited? And what is the reason for having Inherited = true on the RouteAttribute?

Answer (score -1):

Don't use inheritance in Request DTOs. [Inheritance on DTOs are bad idea](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10759250/85785) to begin with, and they should especially be avoided in Request DTO's which should be bespoke for each service.

The Route attribute can be applied on Services and/or Request DTOs and supports the [New API](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/New-Api) and the Old API which allows inheritance.

Comment: If you say that " inheritance" is a bad idea for DTOs (i don't agree on this to be honest) why have inheritance on the route attribute?

Comment: Because you can put the attributes on 'Old API' Service classes.