# ServiceStack.Text how to get subclass values to be serialized?

Tags: c#, json, serialization, servicestack

I have these two classes for example, PropertyEx is inheriting from PropertyDataEx

`public class PropertyDataEx
  {
    public string Name { get; set; }
  }`

public class PropertyEx : PropertyDataEx
  {
    public string Value { get; set; }
  }

When I'm serializing a list of PropertyDataEx with some PropertyEx inside of it, it won't take the property Value, just Name.

`public void Serialize_Property_WillHaveValue() {`

```
  var property = new PropertyEx()
  {Name = "Niclas", Value = "varde"};

  JsConfig.DateHandler = JsonDateHandler.ISO8601;
  JsConfig.ExcludeTypeInfo = false;
  JsConfig.IncludeTypeInfo = true;
  JsConfig.IncludeNullValues = true;
  JsConfig.PreferInterfaces = false;

  var list = new List<PropertyDataEx>();

  list.Add(property);

  var value = JsonSerializer.SerializeToString(list);
}
```

The value will in this case be "[{"__type":"Namespace.PropertyEx, Namespace","Name":"Niclas"}]"

And you see that the property Value is missing.
How can I fix this

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting ServiceStack to retain type information](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10750571/getting-servicestack-to-retain-type-information)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, found it, for this to work the PropertyDataEx needs to be abstract.