# Why do interface IHasResponseStatus use a ServiceStack class?

Tags: servicestack

The interface IHasResponseStatus forces you to implement a ServiceStack class.

Why isn't ResponseStatus another interface and not a class?

Now it's "impossible" to implement the interface IHasResponseStatus since it's one to one with a ServiceStack class.

```cs
namespace ServiceStack.ServiceInterface.ServiceModel
{
///
/// Contract indication that the Response DTO has a ResponseStatus
///
public interface IHasResponseStatus
{
ResponseStatus ResponseStatus { get; set; }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not forced to use `IHasResponseStatus`, it just lets you know what the correct signature is if you want to have include `ResponseStatus` on your DTOs.

Even then you're not forced to include the `ResponseStatus` on your DTO as the [New API](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/New-Api) lets you return clean responses where any exceptions get serialized within a generic `ErrorResponse` DTO. Read the [docs on Error Handling](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Error-Handling#error-response-types) for further info on this.

Other than [interfaces being a terrible idea to have on DTO's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10759250/85785), it's a concrete class in ServiceStack so it can apply the assembly-wide XML Namespace DataContract declaration required by XML and SOAP serializers and endpoints.

Comment: Forces was not the best choice of word. My point is that it´s not a good idea(IMHO) to have your own classes in an interface,  because the point with interfaces is the ability for other(or your self) to have your own classes that implement the interface.

Comment: Interfaces only adds coupling across process boundaries (it's only reduced in code) since the consumer has no idea what concrete type to deserialize into so it has to emit serialization-specific implementation hints that now embeds C# concerns on the wire (so now even C# namespaces will break serialization) and now constrains your response to be used by a particular serializer. It also would not let you specify the xmlns used in XML/SOAP.

Comment: Normally it´s not a good idea to have one to one relationship with an interface and your own classes. This case can be an exception since you want an generic response object where you can control the XML namespace and inheritance using abstract classes would not be the best idea, since c# don´t support inheritance from more than one class and inheritance on DTO is not the best idea as you have described earlier. I see why this approach has been chosen. Thanks for the good explanation.