# ServiceStack JsonSerializer not serializing object members when inheritance

Tags: c#, json, serialization, servicestack, jsonserializer

I'm trying to use ServiceStack.Redis and i notice that when i store an object with members that are object that inheritance from another object and try to get it later on i get null.

I checked and found that ServiceStack.Redis is using ServiceStack.JsonSerializer so I've tried to create a test case:

```
class Program
{
    public class ClassA
    {
        public string Id;

        public Dictionary<string, ClassB> dic = new Dictionary<string, ClassB>();
    }

    public class ClassB
    {
        public string Id;   
    }

    public class ClassC : ClassB
    {
        public object C;
    }

    public class ClassD
    {
        public string Id;
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ClassA t = new ClassA();
        t.Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString("n");
        t.dic.Add("AAA", new ClassC());
        t.dic["AAA"].Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString("n");
        ((ClassC)t.dic["AAA"]).C = new ClassD();
        ((ClassD)((ClassC)t.dic["AAA"]).C).Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString("n");

        ServiceStack.Text.JsConfig.IncludeNullValues = true;
        ServiceStack.Text.JsConfig.IncludePublicFields = true;
        ServiceStack.Text.JsConfig.IncludeTypeInfo = true;
        ServiceStack.Text.JsConfig.MaxDepth = int.MaxValue;

        Console.WriteLine("before SerializeToString data is:");
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(((ClassD)((ClassC)t.dic["AAA"]).C).Id))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("wrong");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("right");
        }

        string a = JsonSerializer.SerializeToString<ClassA>(t);

        ClassA t2 = JsonSerializer.DeserializeFromString<ClassA>(a);

        Console.WriteLine("after SerializeToString data is:");
        if (((ClassC)t2.dic["AAA"]).C == null ||
            string.IsNullOrEmpty(((ClassD)((ClassC)t2.dic["AAA"]).C).Id))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("wrong");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("right");
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

I could find a simpler case when its not working...

As you can see ClassC has a member of type **object** and the class is **inheriting** from ClassB (if you remove the inheritance or give the member another type it will work).

Before serialize the data is "right" and after deserialize the data is "wrong" -> the member  is null.

Can you please help me with that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default ServiceStack only serializes **public properties**. To serialize public fields as well you need to set:

```
JsConfig.IncludePublicFields = true;
```

Also if you want to use inheritance you need to make the sub class abstract or an interface. [See this answer for more info](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10759250/85785).