# ServiceStack and JSV: When I serialize a Dictionary<string, object> the type of 'object' is lost on deserialization

Tags: c#, servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

In a POCO object, that I persiste using OrmLite, I have the following property:

```
....
public Dictionary<string, object> CustomData { get; set; }
...
```

This property is filled with data, like:

```
customData.Add("_GooglePassword", "blabla"); // this is a String
customData.Add("_ServerPort", 8093); // this is an Int32
// etc...
```

It is saved in the database as JSV, like this:

```
{_GooglePassword:blabla,_ServerPort:8093}
```

The problem comes when I deserialize this, back to the Dictionary in C#, then it puts everything back as strings, as this exception in VS shows:

[image]

So, instead of getting it back to an Int32 as it is defined in the class, I get strings, which will give be problems. Im pretty sure that using normal JSON and the DataContract-approach would not have this issue, as I use JSON in other parts.

Am I missing something here?

Thanks =)

Comment: When you deserialize to `Dictionary<string,object>` all your values will be strings. This is the default behavior in JSON serializer too. Why don't you crate a type for your data?

Comment: I have one table that should contain all children of a Settings superclass. The Settings superclass contains some base data, and then each sub-class contains some specific data. But I do not want to create a table for each subclass of settings. Instead, I want to place the properties in the subclass into the "CustomData" field, that I then interpret as can be seen above.

Comment: What about creating a single class for all settings and using interfaces for specific parts? If that's not possible you should use int.TryParse method instead of a direct cast.

Comment: I am using int.tryparse right now. It works, but its not as clean as I would like to... And I dont see how interfaces would help. I think I would just have to stick with try-parses

Answer (score 1):

Some interesting viewpoints of why inheritance in DTOs is a bad idea [from ss author](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10750571/getting-servicestack-to-retain-type-information/10759250#10759250) and [here](http://ayende.com/blog/4769/code-review-guidelines-avoid-inheritance-for-properties).

If your settings can be splitted in profiles, I would suggest you to split in interfaces /classes each cluster of properties and store them in separated strongly-typed properties.

Depending on your context, if you are just storing information and you are not processing or applying business rules to those settings you might receive the dynamic json in a property and storing it as a string. This way you don't create a Settings class just for storing purpose.