# Only specific properties are serialized in metadata

Tags: c#, servicestack

in an application I've got a request that inherits from a base class, I've got a strange problem when I look at the metadata I only get "Max" serialized and not also "Header"

When executing the application it works...it seems to be something wrong when preparing the request stub

```
public class SomeRequest : SomeBaseClass<int>
{
    public int Max { get; set; }
}

public class SomeBaseClass<T> 
{
   public Header SomeHeader { get; set; }

   public T Response {get;set;}
}


public class Header
{
    public int IDUser { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Can anyone help me on this?

P.S. I'm aware the hinerithance inheritance is not good in SS but I've got almost all requests that needs the same header parameter

Thanks

Comment: Did you go with the advice to write your DTOs in full?

Comment: Hello Scott, excuse me for my delay in asnwer...in that way it works! thanks!

Comment: That's great. It is unfortunate there is no easy work around. Please remember to accept the answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have kind of already answered your own question. SS recommends against inheritance, as a result the metadata doesn't support describing your DTO. This is by design. I would follow the recommended design pattern.

Create your objects in full. It is a little more effort, but you will get the right meta data, your service DTO is clear to clients and follows ServiceStack's DRY principle.

```cs
public class SomeRequest
{
    public int Max { get; set; }
    public Header SomeHeader { get; set; }
    public int Response { get; set; }
}
```

*[Quoting mythz (ServiceStack creator) on another DTO inheritance question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10759250/1295344):*

> Inheritance in DTOs is a bad idea - DTO's should be as self-describing as possible and **by using inheritance clients effectively have no idea what the service ultimately returns**. Which is why your DTO classes will fail to de/serialize properly in most 'standards-based' serializers.

The alternative would be to implement your own [MetaDataFeature](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack/MetadataFeature.cs). But that's not an easy task, and so I guess the effort to implement this outweighs writing the full DTO without inheritance.