# ServiceStack: Property in request DTO becomes null if type is abstract

Tags: c#, json, .net-4.0, servicestack, servicestack-bsd

I have a ServiceStack 3-based client-server architecture. I'm trying to create a service whose request DTO contains a property with an abstract type, with two different concrete classes implementing it. The abstract type could be either an abstract class or an interface; however, in either case, the server receives a null object in the property.

There's three assemblies and corresponding namespaces: `TestClient`, `Server`, and `CommonLib` referenced by both client and server.

That is, spread across the three assemblies:

```
namespace CommonLib.Services
{
    public class GetThing : IReturn<GetThingResponse> // request DTO
    {
        public IThisOrThat Context { get; set; }
    }

    public class GetThingResponse
    {
        public Dictionary<int, string> Result { get; private set; }

        public GetThingResponse(Dictionary<int, string> result) // response DTO
        {
            Result = result;
        }
    }
}

namespace CommonLib
{
    public interface IThisOrThat { }

    public class This : IThisOrThat { } // and so forth
}

namespace Server.Services
{
    public class GetThing Service : IService
    {
        public object Get(GetThing request)
        {
            var foo = request.Context; // this is null
        }
    }
}

namespace TestClient
{
    class Program
    {
        public const string WSURL = "http://localhost:61435/";

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (var client = new JsonServiceClient(WSURL))
            {
                var result = client.Get(new GetThing
                                   {
                                       Context = new CommonLib.This("context info")
                                   });
            }
}
```

If I change the `Context` property in `GetThing` to be of type `This` instead of `IThisOrThat`, this works. Leaving it as the interface, or changing `IThisOrThat` to be an abstract class, results in the data being transmitted as `null`.

I'm assuming this is a serialization problem. I've tried changing the interface to an abstract class and decorating that with appropriate `KnownType` attributes, but ServiceStack's serializer doesn't appear to benefit from this. Is there any trick to get this done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to enable `JsConfig.IncludeTypeInfo = true;` on the client side, so the serializer includes the type information with the request. This will add an extra property (`__type`) with the type definition so the service knows what to type it as.

It fails currently because requests by default don't provide type information to deserialize the object into the class that implements the interface. This was an issue that was [previously raised](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/servicestack/vysdfRJlTg8/2zwfRmUBEdYJ).

The problem is the when the JSON client makes the request, it will serialize up the a class that implements `IThisOrThat` such as your `This` class. But when it gets to the other end ServiceStack.Text doesn't know what to deserialize the object into. The type information is lost so it doesn't know what kind of `IThisOrThat` it is. So without the additional `__type` information property in the request this is happening:

Scenario:

```cs
interface ISomething
{
    string Name;
}

class MySomething : ISomething
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}

class MySomethingElse : ISomething
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Size { get; set; }
}
```

Then you make the call from your JsonServiceClient using a typed object

```cs
client.Get(new MySomething { Name: "Duck", Age: 20 });
```

The JSON that is sent would be `{ "Name":"Duck", "Age":20 }` what type does the deserialiser choose now? It could be an `MySomething` or a `MySomethingElse`, or even another `ISomething` that it just doesn't know about yet. So because it can't decide the result is simply `null`.

Generally interfaces and DTOs don't mix, [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10759250/1295344).

Comment: Bingo. `ServiceStack.Text.JsConfig.IncludeTypeInfo = true;` before `client.Get()` does the trick.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem, and realized i didn't have { get; set; } applied to the response DTO, so the result of my object was always null...

Thought this information could also help anyone searching for this ...