# Providing Response Model sample JSON data on the metadata page in ServiceStack

Tags: servicestack

Anyone know a way that you can provide some sample data to show on the metadata page in ServiceStack for your response models?

For this response model

```
public class GetIncidentResponse
{
    public IEnumerable<Incident> Incidents { get; set; } 
}
```

I'm getting this on the metadata page

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: length
{}
```

When I'd like to be able to display something like

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: length
{ "Filter example 1", "Filter example 2"}
```

Comment: Avoid using [interfaces in DTO](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10759250/85785). Use a concrete `List<T>` instead.

Answer (score 1):

@mythz comment fixed my problem. Changing the IEnemerable interfaces to IList worked.