# jsconfig register custom de/serialization for an (tagging) interface

Tags: json, servicestack, servicestack-text

How can i configure Json De/Serialization to use a custom function for a specific type or subclassed types.

I expected that registering a specific De/Serialization function will also be used for subclassed or type that implement the interface.

```
public class FooA {}

public class FooB :FooA {}

JsConfig<FooA>.RawDeserializeFn = x => {}
```

But the function is not used for class FooB types..

i also tried this:

```
public interface IFoo {}

public class Foo :IFoo {}

JsConfig<IFoo>.RawDeserializeFn = x => {}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The typed configuration does not support Open Types, you need to be explicit when configuring  types, e.g:

```
JsConfig<FooA>.RawDeserializeFn = fn;
JsConfig<FooB>.RawDeserializeFn = fn;
```

Comment: @Marco Not really, you could use the [static ParseJson method](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Text/commit/b82ac1e0328acf5a5076de9c526a5b1df8f274b5), otherwise you could try scanning the assemblies yourself for dependent types and hook them up manually, but that requires a bit of effort. Personally I'd go with a flatter model and [avoid inheritance in Serialization all-together](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10759250/85785).