# Paging with KendoUI and ServiceStack using remote data

Tags: kendo-ui, servicestack, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

Is it possible to do server-side paging with ServiceStack and consume it via JSON/AJAX with a KendoUI grid?  I have a large amount of data (30,000+ rows) that will need to be paged.  I need the smallest payload over the wire.  All examples for Kendo's grid shows the paging parameters set client-side but ServiceStack does not appear to use them.  This makes me worried that everything will be sent over the wire.  This is running in a ASP.NET MVC4 application.

Comment: I don't know much about KendoUI grid but you can do similar thing with jQGrid.

Answer (score 3):

You're right that most of the KendoUI examples use client-side paging, which does ship the entire dataset over the wire first.  I ran into this issue a few months back and ultimately chose a different overall approach, but there is what I had.

You can take one of two basic approaches:

1. Configure the KendoUI `DataSource` using the `transport` setting to change the KendoUI query into one that is more copacetic with ServiceStack.
2. Configure "something" in ServiceStack to understand KendoUI paging.

I went with #2, using a global request filter.  This is incomplete code, but the idea was to handle paging, sorting, and filtering.  You might be fine just keeping the `Page`, `PageSize`, `Skip` and `Take` parameters, then manually applying paging.

First, the DTO.  For any ServiceStack DTO, inherit from this base class as well.  I know this flies in the face of Mythz's (very valid) [opinion on DTO design](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10750571/getting-servicestack-to-retain-type-information), but this approach won't work well elsewise.

```
public class KendoQueryBase : IKendoFilter, IKendoSort, IKendoPaged
{
    public FilterTerm Filter { get; set; }
    public List<SortTerm> Sort { get; set; }

    public int? Page { get; set; }
    public int? PageSize { get; set; }
    public int? Skip { get; set; }
    public int? Take { get; set; }
}
```

Then use a global request filter to transform the request into a format that can be interpreted by ServiceStack.  Again, if you're just doing paging, this probably isn't needed.  It is also incomplete, but shows a decent starting point.

```
class KendoQueryPlugin : IPlugin
{
    public void Register(IAppHost appHost)
    {
        appHost.GlobalRequestFilters.Add((req, resp, dto) =>
        {
            if (dto is KendoQueryBase)
            {
                KendoQueryBase qb = dto as KendoQueryBase;
                if (qb.Sort == null) qb.Sort = new List<SortTerm>();
                Dictionary<string, string> qs = req.QueryString.ToDictionary();

                // Create the Sort Terms
                var i = 0;
                while (qs.ContainsKey("sort[{0}][field]".Fmt(i)))
                {
                    qb.Sort.Add(new SortTerm()
                    {
                        Field = qs["sort[{0}][field]".Fmt(i)],
                        Dir = qs["sort[{0}][dir]".Fmt(i)]
                    });
                    i++;
                }

                i = 0;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

### EDIT

To further address paging specifically, I also wrote a helper extension that leverages the [ServiceStack.OrmLite](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite) library and inserts paging into a `SqlExpression`:

```
public static class PagingExtensions
{
    public static SqlExpression<T> Page<T>(this SqlExpression<T> exp, int? page, int? pageSize)
    {
        if (!page.HasValue || !pageSize.HasValue)
            return exp;

        if (page <= 0) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("page", "Page must be a number greater than 0.");
        if (pageSize <= 0) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("pageSize", "PageSize must be a number greater than 0.");

        int skip = (page.Value - 1) * pageSize.Value;
        int take = pageSize.Value;

        return exp.Limit(skip, take);
    }
}
```

You can use it with the above DTO schema like this:

```
if (!request.Page.HasValue) request.Page = 1;
if (!request.PageSize.HasValue || request.PageSize < 0 || request.PageSize > 100)
    request.PageSize = 10;

var exp = Db.From<Your Database Object>
....
var results = Db.Select<YourDTO>(exp.Page(request.Page, request.PageSize)),
```

Comment: This seems great.  Can you post your full plugin, it would be very helpful to others having to integrate into kendo.