# ServiceStack OrmLite mapping with references not working

Tags: c#, entity-framework, servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

I'm trying out OrmLite to see if I can replace Entity Framework in my projects. The speed is quite significant on simple queries. But I tried to map/reference a [1 to many- relation and read the documentation + examined the test code from the github page but without success. This is my example. Is there something I've forgot or should do to get it working like Entity Framework?

***Example***

```cs
// EF: returns +15.000 records + mapped > product.StockItems (slow)
dbContext.Products.Include(x => x.StockItems).ToList();

// OrmLite: returns +100.000 records (NO mapping > product.StockItems)  
db.Select<Product>(db.From<Product>().Join<StockItem>());

// OrmLite: +15.000 separate requests to sql server (bad workarround + slow)
foreach (var product in db.Select<Product>())
{
    // manual mapping
    product.StockItems = db.Select<StockItem>(x => x.ProductId == product.Id);
}
```

***Product.cs***

```cs
public class Product
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public ProductType ProductType { get; set; }         
    public string Name { get; set; }       
    public string Description { get; set; }     
    public int DisplayOrder { get; set; }
    public bool LimitedToStores { get; set; }
    public string Sku { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public decimal OldPrice { get; set; }
    public decimal SpecialPrice { get; set; }
    public decimal DiscountPercentage { get; set; }       
    public DateTime? DateChanged { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DateCreated { get; set; }
    //...

    [Reference] 
    public virtual IList<StockItem> StockItems { get; set; } = new List<StockItem>();

}
```

***StockItem.cs***

```cs
public class StockItem
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    [References(typeof(Product))]
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public string Size { get; set; } 
    public int TotalStockQuantity { get; set; }   
    public string Gtin { get; set; }
    public int DisplayOrder { get; set; }
    // ...

    [Reference] 
    public virtual Product Product { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ideally your [POCOs/DTOs shouldn't use interfaces](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10759250/85785) and you don't need to use `virtual` as ORM only populates your own POCOs (i.e. it doesn't create proxies of your models like other Heavy ORMs), I also prefer to use `[AutoIncrement]` for integer Ids (unless you need to populate specific Ids) so my Models would look like:

```
public class Product
{
    [AutoIncrement]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public ProductType ProductType { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public int DisplayOrder { get; set; }
    public bool LimitedToStores { get; set; }
    public string Sku { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public decimal OldPrice { get; set; }
    public decimal SpecialPrice { get; set; }
    public decimal DiscountPercentage { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DateChanged { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DateCreated { get; set; }

    [Reference]
    public List<StockItem> StockItems { get; set; }
}

public class StockItem
{
    [AutoIncrement]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [References(typeof(Product))]
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public string Size { get; set; }
    public int TotalStockQuantity { get; set; }
    public string Gtin { get; set; }
    public int DisplayOrder { get; set; }
}
```

[OrmLite's POCO References](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite#reference-support-poco-style) only populate 1-level deep and it's not a good idea to have cyclical relationships as they're not serializable so I'd remove the back reference on StockItems as it's not going to be populated.

You also need to use `LoadSelect` in order to [query and return POCOs with references](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite#querying-pocos-with-references), so to return Product with their StockItem references you can just do:

```
db.LoadSelect<Product>();
```

You can also populate this manually with **2 queries** by [using Merge extension method to merge 2 disconnected record sets](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite#merge-disconnected-poco-result-sets), e.g:

```
var q = db.From<Product>().Join<StockItem>();
var products = db.Select(q.SelectDistinct());
var stockItems = db.Select<StockItem>();

products.Merge(stockItems);
```

Which will merge Products with their StockItems which you can quickly see by running:

```
products.PrintDump();
```

Comment: Thx @mythz. Just what I was looking for. Works great. I will continue to convert my projects and replace EF with OrmLite. Performance boost is significant.