# ServiceStack OrmLite Many to One Relationship

Tags: c#, orm, servicestack, many-to-one, ormlite-servicestack

I just started using Service Stack ORMLite for SQL Server and not able to figure out a few things. Let me show you by example, what I am trying to achieve:

I have 2 tables - Users and Roles

```
public partial class Users : IHasId<int>
{
[AutoIncrement]
public int Id { get; set; }
[Required]
public string Email { get; set; }
[Required]
public string Password { get; set; }
[References(typeof(Roles))]
[Required]
public int RolesId { get; set; }
}

public partial class Roles : IHasId<int>
{
[AutoIncrement]
public int Id { get; set; }
[Required]
public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

A user can belong to only 1 Role. But many users can also be part of the same Role. Example:

```
User 1 - Role 1
User 2 - Role 1
User 3 - Role 2
```

When I execute this code

```
db.LoadSelect<Users>(x => x.Id == 1);
```

I get the Users object fine. I want the query to return the Roles object as well (instead of me querying the Roles table separately), how do I do that? What am I missing here? I dont want "How many Users have X Role?" (Typical One 2 Many relationship like this: [ServiceStack OrmLite mapping with references not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42573765/servicestack-ormlite-mapping-with-references-not-working)), instead I want "What is the Role of this User?"

Answer (score 3):

A User can only belong to 1 Role is a 1:1 relationship that is supported in OrmLite using [self references](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite#self-references) by adding a Roles property to your Users table, e.g:

```
public partial class Users : IHasId<int>
{
    [AutoIncrement]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Email { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [References(typeof(Roles))]
    [Required]
    public int RolesId { get; set; }

    [Reference]
    public Roles Roles { get; set; }
}

public partial class Roles : IHasId<int>
{
    [AutoIncrement]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Which will then be populated when using `Load*` APIs, e.g:

```
db.CreateTable<Roles>();
db.CreateTable<Users>();

db.Insert(new Roles { Name = "Role 1" });
db.Insert(new Roles { Name = "Role 2" });

db.Insert(new Users { Email = "user1@gmail.com", Password = "test", RolesId = 1 });
db.Insert(new Users { Email = "user2@gmail.com", Password = "test", RolesId = 1 });
db.Insert(new Users { Email = "user3@gmail.com", Password = "test", RolesId = 2 });

var user1 = db.LoadSelect<Users>(x => x.Id == 1);

user1.PrintDump();
```

Which prints out User 1 and Role 1:

```
[
    {
        Id: 1,
        Email: user1@gmail.com,
        Password: test,
        RolesId: 1,
        Roles: 
        {
            Id: 1,
            Name: Role 1
        }
    }
]
```

I've created a [Live example of this on Gistlyn](http://gistlyn.com/?gist=a212eb962576805c63237f948201d51e&collection=2cc6b5db6afd3ccb0d0149e55fdb3a6a) you can experiment with.