# Implementing Pagination in ServiceStack

Tags: servicestack

## Background

I'm consuming a third party WebApi using ServiceStack. A number of their endpoints paginate the results according to a common schema.

Example JSON:

```
{
    "count": 23,
    "pageSize": 10,
    "pageNumber": 1,
    "_embedded": {
        "people": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "name": "Jean-Luc Picard"
            },
            {
                "id": 2,
                "name": "William T. Riker"
            },
            [...]
        ]
    }
}
```

## Implementation

Since each paginated request and response DTO will have common properties, I've created abstract classes to keep these DTOs DRY.

```
public abstract class PaginatedRequest<TResponseDto, TEmbeddedResponseDto> : IReturn<TResponseDto>
    where TResponseDto : PaginatedResponse<TEmbeddedResponseDto>
{
    public int PageSize { get; set; }
    public int PageNumber { get; set; }

    public List<TEmbeddedResponseDto> Paginate()
    {
        var list = new List<TEmbeddedResponseDto>();

        // Page through results, and add to list until all have been received.

        return list;
    }
}

public abstract class PaginatedResponse<T>
{
    public int Count { get; set; }
    public int PageSize { get; set; }
    public int PageNumber { get; set; }

    public Dictionary<string, List<T>> _embedded { get; set; }
}
```

These abstract classes are then inherited by the request and response DTOs, respectively.

```
public class PersonDto
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}

public class PeopleDto : PaginatedResponse<PersonDto> { }

[Route("/people/{id}")]
public class GetPerson : IReturn<PersonDto>
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
}

[Route("/people")]
public class GetPeople : PaginatedRequest<PeopleDto, PersonDto> { }
```

This can then be called by creating the request DTO, and calling the `Paginate` function.

```
public List<PersonDto> GetPeople() => new GetPeople().Paginate();
```

## Question

Is there a better way to implement this functionality, while remaining DRY? Is there any specific downside to this implementation that I've not considered? I know that [Inheritance in DTOs is Considered Harmful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10750571/getting-servicestack-to-retain-type-information/10759250#10759250), but I think `abstract` base classes avoid those particular issues.

## Update #1

After submitting this, I think moving the Pagination out of the abstract class may alleviate anticipated concerns that the DTOs should be implementation free.

This could be implemented either as a method in my class library, or as an extension method on the `JsonServiceClient` (not shown).

```
public List<TEmbeddedResponseDto> GetPaginated<TResponseDto, TEmbeddedResponseDto>(PaginatedRequest<TResponseDto, TEmbeddedResponseDto> request)
    where TResponseDto : PaginatedResponse<TEmbeddedResponseDto>
{
    var list = new List<TEmbeddedResponseDto>();

    // Page through results, and add to list until all have been received.

    return list;
}

public List<PersonDto> GetPeople() => GetPaginated(new GetPeople());
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked at [AutoQuery](http://docs.servicestack.net/autoquery-rdbms), the entire Request DTO to create a AutoQuery Service for people is:

```
[Route("/people")]
public class QueryPeople : QueryDb<Person> {}
```

For which AutoQuery will automatically provide the Service implementation to create a Service that lets you query and page through `Person` Table.

Which you can paginate with:

```
/people?take=100          # first 100 results
/people?skip=100&take=100 # next 100 results
```

See [Include Total](http://docs.servicestack.net/autoquery-rdbms#include-total) to see how to always include the total or include it on adhoc requests with `?Include=Total`.

You'll also be able to use the [AutoQuery UI](https://github.com/ServiceStack/Admin) to get an instant UI for your AutoQuery Services which lets you page through results and shows you the AutoQuery url used.

Live AutoQuery Viewer Examples

- http://github.servicestack.net/ss_admin/
- http://northwind.servicestack.net/ss_admin/
- http://stackapis.servicestack.net/ss_admin/
- http://techstacks.io/ss_admin/

If you want to do it manually, consider using the same [QueryResponse DTO all AutoQuery Services use](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.Interfaces/IQuery.cs#L157). Then to implement this with [OrmLite](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite), would look something like:

```
public object Any(SearchPeople request)
{
    var q = Db.From<Person>();
    if (request.Age != null) //Query Example
        q.Where(x => x.Age == request.Age.Value);
    if (request.Skip != null)
        q.Skip(request.Skip.Value);
    if (request.Take != null)
        q.Take(request.Take.Value);

    return new QueryResponse<Person>
    {
        Offset = request.Skip ?? 0,
        Results = db.Select<Person>(q),
        Total = db.Count(Q),
    }
}
```

Please also read [designing message-based APIs](http://docs.servicestack.net/design-message-based-apis#keep-a-consistent-nomenclature) which recommends using a consistent nomenclature and reserving `Get*` Services for combintator queries like fetching by primary key(s) and use `Search*` or `Find*` for Services which filter results with additional arguments;

Comment: I hadn't looked at AutoQuery. It looks great, if I was designing the service, but this is a pre-existing third party service. I still plan on looking at RestSharp to see if it fits my use case better, but I'm still analyzing ServiceStack. Implementing a few endpoints, then I'll compare ease of use, ease of maintainability, and performance. I do like the note on nomenclature, and will implement that into my design.