# ServiceStack - Force generation of Typescript types for certain classes

Tags: c#, typescript, servicestack, servicestack-autoquery

I'm working with a backend primarily focused on a ServiceStack API and a Typescript frontend (with the ServiceStack `JsonServiceClient`) interacting with it. This is a large project, so the ability to scale is quite important, and our goal is to have strong type enforcement throughout. Things have been going well so far, but I'm encountering a snag here.

We have an entity that I'll call `Gadget`:

```
public class GadgetDto
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    // other stuff...
}
```

Through AutoQuery, we have an endpoint that returns a list `Gadget`s:

```
[Route("/query/gadgets", HttpMethods.Get)]
public class QueryableGadget : QueryData<GadgetDto>
{
}
```

**However**, the need has arisen to create multiple classes of `Gadget`s, so instead I've refactored to have gadgets derive from a base class and interface:

```
public interface IGadget
{
    int Id { get; set; }
}

public abstract class GadgetBase : IGadget
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

public class TabbedGadget : GadgetBase
{
    public List<Tab> Tabs { get; set; }
}
```

and I've refactored our endpoint to take the interface instead:

```
[Route("/query/gadgets", HttpMethods.Get)]
public class QueryableGadget : QueryData<IGadget>
```

This works well. Since we're using `QueryData`, we can create a `List<IGadget>` that is sent back as a response, with every implementing type included.

The problem I'm having is getting Typescript types generated for derived classes, like `GadgetBase` and `TabbedGadget`. I understand why they're not generated automatically, as the types are not used in the API metadata, but so far I'm clueless as to how to communicate to the Typescript client that the list could contain a concrete number of types that implement `IGadget`, and how to get those types generated.

Is there a way, through some ServiceStack attribute or through a different approach, that I could 'force' the generation of these Typescript types and have them be exposed in the metadata (`/types/typescript`)?

Thanks ahead of time!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd highly recommend against [using interfaces in DTOs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10759250/85785), it's fine to have multiple Request DTOs implement the same interface, but it shouldn't be used in place of a concrete DTO.

Having said that you could create a `Dummy` service that holds a reference to all your DTOs, e.g:

```
public class DummyHolder : IReturnVoid
{
    public GadgetDto GadgetDto { get; set; }
    //...
}

public class DummyService : Service
{
    public void Any(DummyHolder request){}
}
```

Alternatively you can add them to `ExportTypes` in the pre-defined `NativeTypesFeature` in your `AppHost.Configure()`:

```
var nativeTypes = this.GetPlugin<NativeTypesFeature>();
nativeTypes.MetadataTypesConfig.ExportTypes.Add(typeof(GadgetDto));
```

Comment: Excellent. I agree about not using interfaces, especially with how Typescript uses them. That interface came up when trying to make a `List<IGadget>` that could hold all the types and bled over into the endpoint.

But once again, @mythz to the rescue. Thanks again for being so present in the community!