# How to force ServiceStack to serialize an object

Tags: servicestack

I am declaring my reponse-dto like this:

```
[Route("/activity/sync", HttpVerb.Get)]
public class SyncActivityRequest : IReturn<SyncActivityResponse>
{
    public ICollection<SyncParam> ObjectsToSync { get; set; }
}

public class SyncActivityResponse
{
    public ICollection<KeyValuePair<Activity, SyncMetadata>> Result { get; set; }
}
```

The problem is ServiceStack does not serialize Activity and SyncMetadata because those are only type-arguments for another object (KeyValuePair in this case).
Those two objects (activity and syncmetadata) both are declared in the same project.

How can I force the serialization of those two objects?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should [avoid using interfaces or objects in DTOs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10759250/85785), use a concrete Type like `List<T>` or `T[]` instead.