# ServiceStack export C# DTO-Class to dtos.ts file

Tags: c#, angular, servicestack

How can I export a C# class (DTO) in the dtos.ts file generated with `npm run typescript-ref http://localhost:5000 src/myproject` without referencing in the request class?

*Note:* we have several C# DTO classes (MutationAddressChange, MutationCEOChange...) that we map to the domain class using automapper. So we want to use the C# DTO classes as well in Angular to populate the corresponding type (e.g.`MutationAddressChangesCreateDTO`) and send it to the web server. Therefore, in the `CreateMutationRequest` class, we accept an object instead of a specific class.

**example DTO-Class:**

```
public class MutationAddressChangesCreateDTO
{
    public string Street { get; set; }
    public string POBox { get; set; }
    public string Zipcode { get; set; }
}
```

**ServiceStack Request-Class**

```
public class CreateMutationRequest : IPost
{
    public object Mutation { get; set; }
}
```

**Angular expected use:**

```
{
    var mutationAddressChangesCreateDTO= new MutationAddressChangesCreateDTO();
    mutationAddressChangesCreateDTO.dateOfMutation = ...

    const request = new CreateMutationRequest ({
        mutation: mutationAddressChangesCreateDTO,
    });

    this.client.post(request)
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A limitation of [Add ServiceStack Reference](https://docs.servicestack.net/add-servicestack-reference#limitations) feature is that your DTOs cannot have any [object or interface properties](https://docs.servicestack.net/add-servicestack-reference#limitations) which creates a black hole in your Services contract that's impossible to generate a Typed API for.

I'd recommend against having [any object or interface properties](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10759250/85785) in your DTOs which other than being a source of runtime issues is also [limited by security restrictions](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Text#late-bound-object-and-interface-runtime-types).

You could use an untyped data structure like a `Dictionary<string,string>` to store arbitrary values, you can some find other alternatives in this [Customer Forums thread](https://forums.servicestack.net/t/avoiding-interfaces-in-dtos/1927/3?u=mythz).

Although it's discouraged you could still have `object` properties in your ServiceStack Request DTOs, you just wont be able to generate a typed API for them but you should still be able to send them as an anonymous arg, e.g:

```
this.client.post(request, { mutation: dto });
```

Object properties are handled with [JS Utils](https://docs.servicestack.net/js-utils) by default which should deserialize it into a `Dictionary<string,object>` which you should be able to convert back into a C# type using ServiceStack's [Reflection Utils](https://docs.servicestack.net/reflection-utils#converting-instances-from-an-object-dictionary), e.g:

```
public object Any(CreateMutationRequest request)
{
    var payload = request.Mutation as Dictionary<string,object>;
    var payloadRequest = payload.FromObjectDictionary(typeof(TheType));
}
```

A similar approach to this that avoids using `object` is to send a serialized JSON payload in a `string` property, e.g:

```
request.mutation = JSON.stringify(payload);
```

Which you can deserialize using JS Utils again, e.g:

```
public object Any(CreateMutationRequest request)
{
    var payload = JSON.parse(request.Mutation);
    var payloadRequest = payload.FromObjectDictionary(typeof(TheType));
}
```

With that said I don't recommend any of these untyped strategies and would personally create Typed services for each API that's needed which is more intuitive, discoverable & resilient, any shared functionality can easily be handled in your Services implementation using ServiceStack's [AutoMapping](https://docs.servicestack.net/auto-mapping) and .NET's powerful reflection capabilities.

Comment: Thanks a lot for all the effort of explaining the solution. I will go with typed-services as you recommend.